# Unable to find option for creating call style notification from flutter package flutter_local_notifications

Tags: notifications, android-14

How can i create a call style notification using flutter package flutter_local_notifications.

I found a property "category: AndroidNotificationCategory.call" in AndroidNotificationDetails.
But after adding that and setting property "ongoing: true", my notification is still dismissible in android 14.
Can any one guide me or share an example?